# UWP Global Resources is overriden by Local Resources even if not the same property

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have an application resource defined in `App.xaml`. It is tested that the resource applies to the local style if no local resource is defined. So this not some issue like "resource not being initialized".

The code is as below.

**App.xaml**

```
<Application
    ...omitted
    RequestedTheme="Light">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Style/DefaultTheme.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**DefaultTheme.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="50" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
...omitted
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Button Content="Hello" />
    <Button Content="Happy" />
    <Button Content="World" />
</StackPanel>
```

You can see that from the `StackPanel`'s local resources. It is only setting `Width` and `VerticalAlignment` while the global dictionary is assigning `FontSize` and `Background`. There is no contradiction.

I have also tried this syntax in Xamarin Forms XAML. The local resource will only override global resource when they are assigning the same property. Global resources still apply to the element if not specified.

For more information, ReSharper is having a nice icon saying this "Hides resource from DefaultTheme.xaml ". But when I do this in Xamarin Forms, it will fade out only the properties that are being overridden.

Is there a way to make local resources an add on to global resources in UWP? Assigning `x:Key` to the global resource then add `BasedOn` will not be a solution. As I don't think making every button in the app having to derive the global resource make sense in theming.

Comment: Make the default version based on something (but have no X:Key), and then everything that needs to change it bases themselves off the same style the default based itself off.

Comment: thanks @JohnnyWestlake , that make sense for me. so this is confirmed to be the default behavior of UWP, but not me missing something? :s

Comment: Nope, you're not missing anything it's the default behaviour (same for Silverlight and WinRT). Xamarin is the outlier :'(